# How to perform a $_POST for this example below?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple row of buttons in my javascript code which goes from A-Z:

```
<?php
    $a = range("A","Z");
?>

<table id="answerSection">
    <tr>

<?php
    $i = 1;
    foreach($a as $key => $val){
        if($i%7 == 1) echo"<tr><td>";
        echo"<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"btnclick(this);\" value=\"$val\" id=\"answer".$val."\" name=\"answer".$val."Name\" class=\"answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff\">";      
        if($i%7 == 0) echo"</td></tr>";
        $i++;
    }
?>
    </tr>
```

Below is the javascript function where it turns on and off each individual button:

```
function btnclick(btn)
{


$(btn).toggleClass("answerBtnsOff");
$(btn).toggleClass("answerBtnsOn");

    return false;
}
```

I want to perform a $_POST so that it posts all of the buttons which has been turned on. Does anyone know how the post method should be written for this?

Comment: *when* do you want it to post?

Comment: `$(btn).toggleClass("answerBtnsOff answerBtnsOn");`, and you would want to use `$.post` or `$.ajax`

Comment: have you tried anything using AJAX?

Comment: Well I want to use php because I want to insert these details into the database. To be honest I really havnt tried anything because I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: A button is conventionally used to execute something, not to retain states. Sounds like you'd be better off with radio buttons or a checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding a hidden field together with the buttons turned on with the same name as the button. That way you will have the POSTs returned to you with values. This code is not tested but it should work something like this:

```
<?php
$a = range("A","Z");
?>

<table id="answerSection">
<tr>

<?php
$i = 1;
foreach($a as $key => $val){
    if($i%7 == 1) echo"<tr><td>";
    echo"<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"btnclick(this);\" value=\"$val\" id=\"answer".$val."\" name=\"answer".$val."Name\" class=\"answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff\">";
    echo"<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"1\" id=\"hiddenAnswer".$val."\" name=\"hidden".$val."\" class=\"onButtons\">";
    if($i%7 == 0) echo"</td></tr>";
    $i++;
}
?>
</tr>
```

With the following JavaScript (assuming you are using jQuery):

```
function btnclick(btn)
{
    $(btn).toggleClass("answerBtnsOff");
    $(btn).toggleClass("answerBtnsOn");

    var hiddenId = '#hiddenAnswer'+btn.value;
    if ( $(btn).hasClass("answerBtnsOff") )
    {
        $(hiddenId).val('0');
        $(hiddenId).toggleClass('offButtons');
        $(hiddenId).toggleClass('onButtons');       
    }
    else
    {
        $(hiddenId).val('1');
        $(hiddenId).toggleClass('onButtons');
        $(hiddenId).toggleClass('offButtons');
    }   

    return false;
}
```

So if your buttons have the $val's 'Hello', 'World', 'Foo', 'Bar' you will receive the following posts where they are either 1 (button turned on) or 0 (button turned off):

```
$_POST['hiddenHello']
$_POST['hiddenWorld']
$_POST['hiddenFoo']
$_POST['hiddenBar']
```

Notice that all buttons are "turned on" from the start.

Comment: can you give me a quick sample of your code? Its just so I know what to call the hidden input

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you want to submit the form. If you just want to submit it as a normal form and you dont want the off buttons submitted, you could mark them as disabled with the disabled html attribute. That way they wont be posted

If you are using ajax you will need to get the values and post them with $.post or $.ajax

eg.

```
$(btn).attr('disabled',true);
```

Comment: What I want to do is that when the user submits the form, I want it to go onto a seperate php page which it does where it performs all of the inserting values into the database. Really what i want to do is retrieve the values of all of the buttons turned on and insert them in the database. I got the database code all set up, I just don't know how in php to $_POST the turned on buttons only

Comment: as I suggested mark the off buttons as disabled when you add the class. I have added an example. Disabled form elements do not get posted.

Comment: Actually thinking about it, this would be a weird ui, as you wouldnt be able to reenable the buttons. Radio buttons or checkboxes would be a better option as suggested in a comment above